# Popup isn't closed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, popup

After navigating to other usercontrol by shortcut,popups are still opened.
Staysopen prop is false

`FocusManager.SetFocusedElement` doesn't help.

Only found one ugly,bad answer-simulate click by winapi but i don't want to use it.
currently i'm doing something like this

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);

    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Win32Point pt);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct Win32Point
    {
        public Int32 X;
        public Int32 Y;
    };
    private static Point GetMousePosition()
    {
        Win32Point w32Mouse = new Win32Point();
        GetCursorPos(ref w32Mouse);
        return new Point(w32Mouse.X, w32Mouse.Y);
    }

    private void ShowOpenControlExecute(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var labelEditor = WorkspaceService.SelectedItem.Content as LabelEditor;
        var mousepoint = GetMousePosition();

        Menu.OpenedTabName = WorkspaceService.SelectedItem.Name;
        Menu.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        Menu.ShowOpenControl();
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, Convert.ToUInt32(mousepoint.X), Convert.ToUInt32(mousepoint.Y), 0, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided that we should restrict using shortcuts while pop up is opened(dropdownlist etc).

That's the only solution we have gotten

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`Popup.IsOpen` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.isopen(v=vs.110).aspx) to open and close your `Popup` controls. Here is a very simple XAML example that demonstrates this:

```
<Grid>
    <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton" Content="Click to toggle Popup" />
    <Popup Placement="Relative">
        <Border Background="White" CornerRadius="3" Padding="3">
            <TextBlock Text="I'm a Popup" />
        </Border>
        <Popup.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, 
                        ElementName=ToggleButton}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Popup.Style>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It wouldn't help. We should close all popups,all combobox with dropdownlist as they actually are toggle buttons with popup.

Comment: What part of this example showing you how to close a `Popup` wouldn't help exactly? It can totally solve your problem and correctly answers your question. If you cannot extrapolate a solution for your problem from this, that really isn't my fault.

Comment: We have already solve it. Just restrict user to use shortcuts while popup is opened as it implemented into a lot of applications

Comment: Then add an answer describing your solution and then accept it.